# Where should I ask a question about if a cookie notice is required on my website?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> I'm using [GoSquared](https://gosquared.com) for my website analytics.
>
> I've visited quite a few sites using Google Analytics but they don't have a cookie policy or a cookie banner/cookie notice, even though Google Analytics uses cookies to provide their services.
>
> Do I need to make my own cookie policy or cookie notice if I use GoSquared Analytics (which also uses cookies to function)?

Which site would the above question be on-topic for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a legal question, so perhaps [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) is your best bet.

The usual advice: please [search](https://law.stackexchange.com/search) and check their Help Center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question.

<sub>P.S. [it seems](https://consent.guide/google-analytics-cookie-consent/) sites with Google Analytics *do* need to present a cookie consent notice, at least when you're in the European Union.</sub>

Comment: If this is the GDPR it is not just if you are in the EU - it is also if the client is in or a citizen of the EU.